# Are Local Refernece varibles also called as Composition?

Tags: java, composition, instance-variables, local-variables, object-composition

*Java_Composition: A class can have references to objects of other classes as members.*

**Question**?: Should that be a Instance-variable of a class to call it as Composition Or it is also called as Composition, if it is a Local-variable ?

Demo: Preceding **question** for local reference-type variables at lines 5 and 6.

```
1   public class EmployeeTest
2   {
3   public static void main(String[] args)
4   {
5     Date birthday;
6     Date birth = new Date(12, 12, 1950);
7   }
8   }
```

Comment: Are you asking if `birth` is an instance variable of `EmployeeTest`?

Comment: Local variables are not members of the class. They come and go as the method is entered and exited. They are not involved in either composition or inheritance.

Comment: You asking - if declared variable(object) is local or instance, can we call both as Composition?

Comment: @Blasanka  yes I m asling that.,

Answer (score 1):

> *Should that be a Instance-variable of a class to call it as Composition Or it is also called as Composition, if it is a Local-variable?*

Not really, remember Composition is also known as ***HAS-A*** relationship,

so ask yourself the question:

> EmployeeTest has a date?

the answer is NO, the date is only scoped in a method and nowhere else...

so that is not Composition.